# Retrieve HTML ID field using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am, trying to retrieve a html id using java script rather than the value:

```
<form name="f">
<select name='sel'>
<option id='id1' value='$value1'>$value1</option>
<option id='id2' value='$value2'>$value2</option>
<option id='id3' value='$value3'>$value3</option>
</select>
<textarea rows='4' cols='50' name='devModules'></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.forms['f'].elements['sel'].onchange = function(){document.forms['f'].elements['devModules'].value += this.value + ',';};                  
 </script>
</form>
```

However I cannot manipulate this line of JS to get what I need, from other posts I gather I simply change .value to .id however I am still not able to get this to work.

Or if that is not easily possible, could I store an array in the value, and using the JS retrieve the first or second piece of data, send that to the text area? Whilst keeping the other half to send on and parse server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way;

```
document.forms['f'].elements['sel'].onchange = function(){
    var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    document.forms['f'].elements['devModules'].value += selected.id + ',';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<form name="f">
<select name='sel'>
<option id='id1' value='$value1'>$value1</option>
<option id='id2' value='$value2'>$value2</option>
<option id='id3' value='$value3'>$value3</option>
</select>
<textarea rows='4' cols='50' name='devModules'></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.forms['f'].elements['sel'].onchange = function(){
  //document.forms['f'].elements['devModules'].value += this.value + ',';
  console.log(this[this.selectedIndex].value); // get value
  console.log(this[this.selectedIndex].id); // get id
};                  
 </script>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't forget to validate my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        document.forms['f'].elements['sel'].onchange = function(){document.forms['f'].elements['devModules'].value += this.options[this.selectedIndex].id + ',';};                  
     </script>
```